# Distributional derivative of $\frac{1}{r^n}$

Tags: functional-analysis

On $\mathbb{R}^n$, I don't know distributional derivative of $\frac{1}{r^n}$  where $r$ is norm of $x$. (i.e. distance of from origin to $x$)

I want to use integration by parts.
But, i don't know detail... Please help me!